# Android align button to center and make sure they are evenly spaced out

Tags: android, xml, button, android-layout-weight

[image]

I got a Main Menu with four buttons (attached), I would like to align all buttons to the center (including the "Main Menu" textView), and I would like to make sure that each buttons are all evenly spaced out.

I added android:gravity="center"> but its not aligning to center. Also to evenly space out the buttons I tried to add android:layout_weight="1" as one of the Button attributes but my button disappears from the screen.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

   <TextView android:text="Main Menu" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button android:text="Button" 
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    <Button android:text="Button" 
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    <Button android:text="Button" 
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    <Button android:text="Button" 
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `android:layout_gravity="center"` and  `android:gravity="center"` for your button and textView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your LinearLayout width and height from wrap_content to match_parent..like this..

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

   <TextView android:text="Main Menu" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button android:text="Button" 
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="55dp"/>
    <Button android:text="Button" 
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="55dp"/>
    <Button android:text="Button" 
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="55dp"/>
    <Button android:text="Button" 
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="55dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

no need to hard code the height of the view or `0dp`, if you want to set the `waight then only height is 0dp`. check all the line i given here.

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Main Menu" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Main Menu" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```